# Auto vertical scrolling of RichTextBox on panel scrolling c#

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` inside a panel in a `WinForm`. I want to hide the vertical scroll bar of `RichTextBox` and synchronize its scrolling with the vertical scroll bar of the container panel; whenever text overflows in the `textbox` the scroll bar of the panel should show up and whenever I scroll the scroll bar of the panel the `textbox` should scroll. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: Your panel contains only the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: Yes it has only one RichTextBox

Comment: This is possibly done using some hack, however to make it work like as the real vertical scrollbar of the RichTextBox, you have to deal with some win32 messages, not easy. For example, if you use `Up` or `Down` arrow key to move the `caret` up or down, the scrollbar thumb should also move accordingly, there are some other situations, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, we have to deal with win32 message and use some hack. I've used all my knowledge about win32 message and control hack/customization in `winforms` to make this demo for you. It's not complete and of course won't be as perfect as the standard scrollbars of the `RichTextBox`. The deficiency is if you keep holding down the arrow keys, the scrollbar thumb won't be moved right, however if you press the arrow keys normally the scrollbar thumb will move the caret into view as the standard scrollbars do. You can try the code yourself to see it in action:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
   [DllImport("user32")]
   private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      //initialize some properties for your richTextBox1 (this should be added as a child of your panel1)
      richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Horizontal;
      richTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
      richTextBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(panel1.Width, panel1.Height - 2);
      //initialize some properties for your panel1
      panel1.AutoScroll = true;
      panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;       
      //If the size of panel1 is changed, we have to update the MinimumSize of richTextBox1.
      panel1.SizeChanged += (s,e) => {
         richTextBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(panel1.Width, panel1.Height - 2);
      };   
      new NativeRichTextBox() { Parent = panel1 }.AssignHandle(richTextBox1.Handle);
      hidden.Parent = panel1;    
   }
   //hidden control of panel1 is used to scroll the thumb when the KeyUp of richTextBox1 is raised.
   Control hidden = new Control();
   //this is used to hook into the message loop of the richTextBox1
   public class NativeRichTextBox : NativeWindow
    {
        public Panel Parent;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {

            if (m.Msg == 0x20a)//WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
            {                    
                if (Parent != null)
                {
                    SendMessage(Parent.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);                     
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);                
        }
    }
   //ContentsResized event handler of your richTextBox1
   private void richTextBox1_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height + 5;            
    }
   //KeyUp event handler of your richTextBox1
   private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            Point p = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);                                
            hidden.Top = panel1.PointToClient(richTextBox1.PointToScreen(p)).Y;
            hidden.Height = (int) richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Height;
            panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(hidden);                
    }
}
```

**Note:** you have to register the event handlers `ContentsResized` and `KeyUp` for your `richTextBox1` either using code or by designer.

Answer (score 0):

in order to hide the scroll bars you can do

```
richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
```

but the problem with it is that it makes the text warp. so you also need

```
richTextBox1.WordWrap = false;
```

once you've done that the rest isn't that easy too.

register on the event of the panel scrolling and change the scroll on the rich text box. the problem is is that you can't just change is scrolling offset of the `richTextBox`, so you can use the `Select` method to jump to the place you need. you can use the length of the line to know what's the size of the `scrollBar` need to be.

at the end, it's gonna be a hard time work. good luck